# Vimeo API php connection issues

Tags: php, api, get, request, vimeo

I am utilizing the Vimeo API to try and display my videos. I have set-up an App on developer.vimeo.com/apps/, while also creating authentication tokens for the app. I have downloaded and included the Vimeo-Php API found [here](https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo.php), but am still having no luck display anything, let alone a specific video, group, etc. I have posted the simple steps recommended on the Github to authenticate with Vimeo as I believe that I am missing something along the way.

```
/*includeds at the top of my file */ 
include("../vimeo/autoload.php");

//following variables from developer.vimeo.com/apps/MYAPPID
$client_id = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
$client_secret = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
$clientToken = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';

$lib = new Vimeo($client_id, $client_secret, $clientToken);
$search_results = $lib->request('/videos', array('page' => 1, 'per_page' => 50, 'query' => urlencode($_GET['query']), 'sort' => 'relevant', 'direction' => 'desc', 'filter' => 'CC'));
return $search_results;
```

Comment: Do you get *anything* at all in the `$search_results` variable?

Comment: No, I wasn't being returned anything. With no success I ended up just doing a workaround with my own request method including the token in the header content. Although I would rather use the class functions provided time did not permit a thorough inquiry.